# Little problem with accordion-menu (hide/show)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good time. There is an accordion menu at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3Z0U159KFM3
(to see it, you need to click on the green "Run" button)

This is a simple show / hide menu. How to make the default content was expanded and by clicking could hide it? (i.e. the opposite of the current one)

Dears, please help with this problem.

Comment: Please include the code you are having problems with in your question body. Links to external sites can be problematic.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] of what you have tried so for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although the way you described your issue wasn't clear, I think you are trying to do the opposite of the code you provided, so you would like the "contents" menu to be shown by default and when you click on it the menu would collapse back.

First you want to set the `.active` class by default to the `.ContentsAccordion` button like so :

```
<button class="ContentsAccordion active">Contents</button>
```

And then you want to get the height of your menu and put it into the `style` element of your `.ContentsPanel` div with this code :

```
var pan = document.getElementsByClassName("ContentsPanel");
pan[0].setAttribute('style', 'max-height: ' + pan[0].scrollHeight + 'px;');
```

and the rest of your code doesn't need any change.

Working example below :

```html
<style>
.ContentsAccordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.ContentsAccordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.ContentsAccordion.active:after {
    content: '\2212';
}

.active, .ContentsAccordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.ContentsPanel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.ContentsAccordionP {
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

<button class="ContentsAccordion active">Contents</button>
<div class="ContentsPanel">
  <a href="#"><p class="ContentsAccordionP">Some text 1</p></a>
  <a href="#"><p class="ContentsAccordionP">Some text 2</p></a>
  <a href="#"><p class="ContentsAccordionP">Some text 3</p></a>
</div>


<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("ContentsAccordion");
var i;

var pan = document.getElementsByClassName("ContentsPanel");
pan[0].setAttribute('style', 'max-height: ' + pan[0].scrollHeight + 'px;');

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```